# Meaning of the expression "flush right up"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading an Agatha Christie'es book, Appointment with Death and I don't understand this sentence:

> The boy flushed right up to the roots of his hair

The boy was pulling his hair? He was scratching his head a lot?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Excellent question! Thank you so much for telling us exactly what confused you and what you thought it meant. That's exactly what we hope for in questions :). I hope you stick around and ask more!

Comment: Oh thank you! Your comment make me flushed up to the roots of my hair! hahaha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Flush" in this context is another word for "blush". In other words, the boy's face turned red. But while a blush starts in the cheeks, this one spread all across his face, all the way up ("right up") to the top of his forehead ("the roots of his hair").

Comment: +1 it's verb here and *right up* means all the way. The situation has turned his face flushed.